# gaussian mixture model (GMM) mllib Apache Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, gaussian, apache-spark-mllib, mixture-model

I do not think gaussian mixture model is available in mllib yet. I am wondering if any good Scala/Java implementation of GMM (suitable for large data) is available elsewhere. Please let me know.

Thanks and regards,

Comment: So far, I have found the following:  https://github.com/FlytxtRnD/GMM

Answer (score 1):

It is available in Spark MLlib now:

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-clustering.html#gaussian-mixture

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4156
It is still under progress. We can expect it soon in MLLib.